# Keycloak: Validate access token and get keycloak ID

Tags: json, curl, keycloak

I need to be able to do the following (with plain cURL & JSON server-side- no frameworks or Java):

1. Use a string representation of a Keycloak access token I have been given by a 3rd party to verify that the token is valid.
2. If the token is valid, get the Keycloak ID for that user.

How do I do this using plain old HTTP posts? I've found lots of Java examples but I need to know the raw HTTP POSTs and responses underneath.

Is it something like this to validate the token?

```
/auth/realms/<realm>/protocols/openid-connect/validate?access_token=accesstokenhere
```

What does this return in terms of data (sorry I currently have no test server to interrogate)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need this:
http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-April/005869.html

The only one problem is that, introspect is not working with public clients.

The key url is:
"http://$KC_SERVER/$KC_CONTEXT/realms/$REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"

You need to authorize your client e.g. with basic auth, and need to give the requester token to introspect:

```
curl -u "client_id:client_secret" -d "token=access_token_to_introspect" "http://$KC_SERVER/$KC_CONTEXT/realms/$REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"
```

Comment: when you say that introspect is not working with public clients, you mean front apps (react, angular,...) that uses browser ? Because actually I can consume keycloak intrsopect endopint from postman, curl, backend node app, but I have an CORS error when I tried to access from my front app.

Answer (score 3):

The validate endpoint does not seem to work now. It used to return access token. I am using the keycloak 2.5.1 now. As mentioned in post by Matyas (and in the [post](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-April/005869.html) referenced by him), had to use [introspect](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_service_protection_token_introspection) token endpoint.

In my testing Bearer authentication did not work. Had to use Basic authentication header along with base64 encoded **client credentials**.

```
base64.encode("<client_id:client_secret>".getBytes("utf-8"))
```

The response from introspect endpoint is in JSON format as shared in post referenced by Maytas, has many fields based on type of token being introspected. In my case *token_type_hint* was set as *access_token*.

```
requestParams = "token_type_hint=access_token&token=" + accessToken
```

The response included required user details like username, roles and resource access. Also included OAuth mandated attributes like active, exp, iss etc. See rfc7662#page-6 for details.