# Keycloak Introspection Endpoint

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, keycloak, introspection, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to access to introspect endpoint in my Keycloak server */openid-connect/token/introspect* from my front app, but I get next error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/backoffice/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Using Postman, curl or Node app this request works fine, but from my front-app using fetch method thows this error. I'm not sure it's possible query for introspect endpoint from front-app in the browser or if it's only possible from server app.

Other endpoints like:

- openid-connect/token:
- openid-connect/userinfo:

Works fine using the Postman JS code.

### Keycloak config

My client in Keycloak has set up ***Web Origins **** and ***Access Type confidential***.

[image: Keycloak Config Client]

### Client Code

My front app is simply the Postman code JS, and I deploy it using node http-server.

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("client_id", "my-client");
urlencoded.append("client_secret", "my-secret");
urlencoded.append("token", "eyJ...oCA");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/backoffice/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

### Header Response

The header response in **userinfo endpoint** comes with Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials but **is not present in introspect endpoint**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, the Keycloak server prevents the CORS headers to be set for the introspection endpoint. This could be a bug or by design. I tried it and I get the same error.

If you really want to access the introspect endpoint from the web app, you could set up a NGINX reverse-proxy in front of your Keycloak server and use it to add the missing headers.

That being said, according to [oauth.com](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/token-introspection-endpoint/) you should not leave the introspection endpoint available to the public, which is what you are currently doing since anyone can retrieve the client id and secret from your web app.

> If the introspection endpoint is left open and un-throttled, it presents a means for an attacker to poll the endpoint fishing for a valid token. To prevent this, the server must either require authentication of the clients using the endpoint, or only make the endpoint available to internal servers through other means such as a firewall.

This could explain the decision not to allow CORS.

Another thing, it looks like you forgot to set the `token_type_hint` check out this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893059/keycloak-validate-access-token-and-get-keycloak-id) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I really doubted if it was a mistake or if it was working fine according to some standard, and yes, I also tried with that parameter _token_type_hint_ but is optional